# Get universal image loader instance from a library - Android

Tags: android

I'm using universal image library in my app and now I'm using a library and I need to call the UIL instance from the inside it to load the images,

When I do the following inside the library

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

Android studio suggests this

```
"Add library "universal-image-loader-1.9.3" to classpath
```

and I do click on it and the editor doesn't complain about it anymore, but when I try to build it the compiler complains with the following,

```
Error:(12, 46) error: package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core does not exist
Error:(21, 5) error: cannot find symbol class ImageLoader
Error:(21, 31) error: cannot find symbol variable ImageLoader
```

and I did add the dependency to the library gradle and it didn't work as well,

What should I do?

Comment: Did you add the **dependency** in your `gradle` file? `compile'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'`

Comment: yes and it didn't help, i'll add that to the above

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I got the errors in the quesiton

Comment: I got the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding jar files to your libs folder always works. Download jar file from [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#downloads) and add dependency in your Gradle file.